# Domain name different from Forest

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

We are planning to build a new forest and multiple domains. We want to know if it is possible to have the name of the domain not inherit from the forest. For example

Forest: abc.com
Domain 1: xyz.com
Domain 2: def.com

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

The first domain in the forest is knows as the "forest root domain" and shares a name with the forest. So, in the configuration that you're describing, you'll actually need three domains. The forest root will be `abc.com`, then you can have two new tree-root domains named `xyz.com` and `def.com`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. You had to create a new Tree Root Domain.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755319%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: This isn't technically correct. See the answer MDMarra provided. The first domain in the forest shares the forest name. The second and subsequent domains can diverge from the namespace of the forest/root domain.

Comment: i agree that my answer is quick and short without detail but it is technically correct. Monshine was asking "..Want to know if it is possible to have the name of the domain not inherit from the forest." -> yes it is with Tree Root Domains

Comment: It's not possible to have the first Domain not share the Forest name, which is part of what the OP is asking. You're correct for the second and subsequent Domains but not for the first Domain. Why not edit your answer to reflect that?